# Spark sql get collect_set ignore null on other columns

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need union result and collect set but want to ignore null

```
val df1 = Seq(
  ("1","Adam","Angra", "Anastasia")
).toDF("id","fname", "mname", "lname")
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("df1")

val df2 = Seq(
  ("1",null,null, "Bosma")
).toDF("id","fname", "mname", "lname")
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("df2")
```

df2 dataframe always has fname and mname null - I need lname concatenated as list when grouped by id

Current query:

```
select id,fname,mname,collect_set(lname) as lname from (select * from df1 union select * from df2) group by id,fname, mname
```

Actual Output

```
id  fname   mname   lname
1   Adam    Angra   ["Anastasia"]
1   null    null    ["Bosma"]
```

Expected Output

```
id  fname   mname   lname
1   Adam    Angra   ["Anastasia","Bosma"]
```

Need help to get above expected result with SQL query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by `id` and use the `first` function (ignoring `null` values) to get `fname`, `mname`.

```
val sql = """
    select id,first(fname, true) as fname,first(mname, true) as mname,collect_set(lname) as lname from
        (select * from df1 union select * from df2)
    group by id
"""
val df = spark.sql(sql)
df.show()
```

Comment: Will this first(column_name,true) work for any datatype? Like array and struct as well?

Comment: Yes, it works with array and struct,  but the result may not be what you expected. You can give sample data to explore together.

Comment: Sure, I can have examples same as in this question. Should I ask them as a separate questions 1 for array and 1 for Structs?

Comment: There is no need to separate them, just combine them into one question.